# How to authenticate and authorize a user in username/password and google sign in?

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt, authorization

The architecture of the system is like this

1. User can log into the website using either username-password approach (after registration) or a google-sign-in.

I want to know how can I implement authentication and authorization for this scenario.

Here is what I am thinking of implementing :

1. Have an REST API server built over NodeJS and Express.
2. The login and registration processes are handled by this server as well.
3. The authentication is done by using **JWT Tokens** stored in the client side. And these tokens are then used again for authorization of endpoints as well.

How much secure is this approach? And how can google sign in be added to this architecture.
And also if a seperate server for making auth requests is needed as mentioned in OAuth 2.0?

It would be better if the system remains Stateless to follow the principles of RESTFul APIs.

Answer (score 0):

This post that I have written might give you some insight.

https://dev.to/ralphwjz/login-management-for-spa-and-everyone-else-12o6

The post covers Github login but if you replace GitHub with google, the rest of the flow is exactly the same.

I can answer more questions once in context